# android: unable to upload file to FTP server

Tags: android, ftp

I am trying to upload an audio file from the sdcard to an ftp server. The logcat shows the following messages..

```
     09-04 18:47:10.767: W/System.err(12584): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 21): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:120)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:849)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:176)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:268)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at com.example.andro.MainActivity$AsyncUpload.ftpUpload(MainActivity.java:56)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at com.example.andro.MainActivity$AsyncUpload.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:91)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at com.example.andro.MainActivity$AsyncUpload.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-04 18:47:10.777: W/System.err(12584): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
09-04 18:47:10.787: W/System.err(12584):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
09-04 18:47:10.787: W/System.err(12584):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
09-04 18:47:10.787: W/System.err(12584):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:133)
09-04 18:47:10.787: W/System.err(12584):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:118)
09-04 18:47:10.787: W/System.err(12584):    ... 15 more
09-04 18:47:10.787: W/dalvikvm(12584): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:471)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:534)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:583)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.quit(FTP.java:794)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.logout(FTPClient.java:697)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at com.example.andro.MainActivity$AsyncUpload.ftpUpload(MainActivity.java:79)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at com.example.andro.MainActivity$AsyncUpload.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:91)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at com.example.andro.MainActivity$AsyncUpload.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-04 18:47:10.797: E/AndroidRuntime(12584):    ... 5 more
```

My code is:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    TextView tv1;   
    Button bt1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(new AsyncUpload().execute() != null)
            tv1.setText("uploaded");
        }
    });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    class AsyncUpload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{       
        public boolean ftpUpload(){
            FTPClient con = new FTPClient();
            try
            {

                con.connect("127.0.0.1"); //here i receive exception
                    //the exception is java.unknownhostexception
                    //java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "ftp.194.90.81.149": No address associated with hostname
                if (con.login("android", "123"))
                {
                    con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); 
                    String data = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "audiorecordtest.3gp";
                    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
                    boolean result = con.storeFile("/test.3gp", in);
                    in.close();
                    if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try
            {
                con.logout();
                con.disconnect();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            ftpUpload();
            return null;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: please format your logcat output

Comment: also, the problem is not to upload a file, but rather that the FTPClient class is not included in your project.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient`
I think the problem is how you link the external library

Comment: include the jar file or the external project in your build path

Comment: Rather than config the external lib in build path, create a folder called "libs" under the project root. put the jar there, and refresh the project, ADT should auto include the jar for you.

Comment: @xandy i tried what you told but still the problem exists.. i have edited the logcat messages.

Comment: the problem was changed already, now you HAVE the library correctly linked, but some problem with your FTP commands.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know this one will work or not.Try and let me know

Code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {   

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
            // configure the notification          
            notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.uploadprogress);
            notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
            notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_icon, R.drawable.progressbar);
            notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_text, "Uploading...");
            notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, progress, false);

            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                    getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(10, notification);

            final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            UUID uniqueKey = UUID.randomUUID();
                fname = uniqueKey.toString();
                Log.e("UNIQUE NAME", fname);
                String hostName = "MY HOST NAME";
                String username = "test";
                String password = "****";
                String location = selectedPath;         
                InputStream in = null;
                try {
                    Thread upload = new Thread() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {   
                                progress=progress+1;
                                notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, progress, false);                               
                                // inform the progress bar of updates in progress
                                notificationManager.notify(id, notification);                      
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }      
                        }
                    };
                    upload.run();
                    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
                    ftp.connect(hostName);
                    ftp.login(username, password);

                    ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/uploads");

                    int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
                    System.out.println("Received Reply from FTP Connection:" + reply);

                    if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                        System.out.println("Connected Success");
                    }

                    File f1 = new File(location);
                    in = new FileInputStream(f1);

                    ftp.storeFile(fname+"."+extension, in);

                    System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                    System.out.println("Video Title:" +strTitle+" is uploaded successfully");
                    System.out.println("Video Name:" +fname+" is uploaded successfully");
                    ftp.logout();
                    ftp.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                StringBuffer inStreamBuf = new StringBuffer();
                strUserName = prefs.getString(
                        getResources().getString(R.string.username), null);
                strToken = prefs.getString(
                        getResources().getString(R.string.token), null);
                url = prefs.getString("VALUE", null);
                try {                   
                        inStreamBuf = XmlUtil.getUploadAuthResponse(url,
                                strUserName, strToken, strType, strTitle,
                                fname, strDesc, strCatId, strTags, strAccess,
                                strComments, strEmbed, strRating, strPublish);
                        strXmlResponse = inStreamBuf.toString();
                        Log.e("Response:", strXmlResponse);
                        DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory
                                .newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                        InputSource is = new InputSource();
                        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(strXmlResponse));
                        Document doc = db.parse(is);
                        NodeList nodes = doc
                                .getElementsByTagName(getResources().getString(
                                        R.string.xmlResponse));
                        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(0);
                        NodeList nl_request_type = element
                                .getElementsByTagName(getResources().getString(
                                        R.string.response));
                        Element el_request_type = (Element) nl_request_type
                                .item(0);
                        String strType = getCharacterDataFromElement(el_request_type);
                        // System.out.println("Response----------->"+strType);
                        if (strType.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(
                                R.string.success))) {   
                            finish();
                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(NewVideoActivity.this,
                                    MainscreenActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (strType.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources()
                                .getString(R.string.expired))) {
                            XmlUtil.session = null;
                            Intent intent2 = new Intent(NewVideoActivity.this,
                                    MainscreenActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                            System.exit(0);
                        }                                           
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
                notificationManager.cancel(10); 
                return null;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're linked your FTP library in compile or test scope (e. g. IDEA allows such trick), so it's here on compilation but is absent in runtime. Which IDE do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with your FTP connection. Which says permission denied..

Please add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in your manifest

Comment: ok then instead of adding 127.0.0.1 or localhost use your real IP address like 192.168.0.1 etc..